# Piece-wise Function Differentable, and Continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

I have this piece-wise function:

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> 2x+3 & \text{x$\le4$} \\
> x^2-5 &\text{x$\gt 4$}\end{cases}$$

I know the function is continuous at $x=4$ except how would I go finding out if it were differentable at that point?

I tried by taking the derivative of the top portion and the bottom portion and got

> $$2$$
>   $$2x$$

Then I plugged in $4$ for both and got $2$, and $8$.  Since $2 \ne 8$ I deduced that at $x=4$ the function is not differentable.  Is my ideology correct of am I wrong?

Comment: You are on the right track.  You have a limit that defines your derivative.  What is the left hand and right hand limit?  If the left hand limit does not equal the right hand limit, the limit does not exist at 4, and the function is not differentiable at 4.  This is pretty much what you did, with a little bit more formality why.

Comment: @DougM I was utterly confused at the problem, so i guessed if the derivatives did not equal each other at that point, then it would be non-differentable.

Comment: Good intuition.  Do you have a better understanding why?

Comment: @DougM Using the answer below I guess since the limits from both sides of the original functions in the piece-wise function do not equal other then they at that point, then at $x=4$ the function is not differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can immediately deduce from your observation is that the function cannot be continuously differentiable (in that point). It's also not difficult to see that it also cannot be differentiable, but strictly speaking (esp if you are not sure about what you just wrote down) you would  need  to/should either check the definition or make use of some theorem which contradicts your observation.

You can, e.g., just use the fact that you would need to have 
$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $ has to exist and to be $=f^\prime(4)$ regardless of whether $h$ approaches $4$ from left or right. In the first case the limit is $2$, in the second case it will be $8$.